# gdb - debugging with piped input (not arguments)

Tags: gdb, pipe

I typically run my program with:

```
perl -e 'print "A"x200' | ./vuln_prog
```

The stdin is consumed by a `gets()` function in C++.

If this were just a command argument, I could open gdb by doing:

```
gdb ./vuln_prog
run $(perl -e 'print "A"x200')
```

However, my scenario is not a command argument, but rather input (STDIN?).  How would I debug this in gdb?  I've tried a bunch of options, but nothing seems to really work.

I would normally just run gdb on the process, and when it prompts for user input, type it in, however I'm not wanting to type just "A".  I want to type all chars from \x00-\xff, which I can't type.

Comment: Why are you using `gets`? I mean sometimes it's acceptable (like if you're just writing a quick program to test something, or if the program will only be run with trusted input) but I'm curious.

Comment: It was not my code. It was for a fun reverse engineering challenge, where the code was provided.

Comment: Oh okay. Was `gets` intentionally used *because* it was vulnerable, like as part of a possible solution to the challenge?

Comment: @flarn2006 Indeed it was the vulnerable function. I was able to do a buffer overflow due to it not bound-checking.

Comment: `r < <(perl -e 'print "A"x200')`

(as the question is closed, not as answer)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
gdb ./vuln_prog
run < filename_with_input
```

Comment: Thank you SO much.  I was trying to run the input directly, where I should have thought to just print the perl code to a file, and input it.  That worked marvelously.

Comment: Does the have a `lldb` equivalent?

Comment: @ThomasAhle For lldb equivalent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861242/cannot-get-mac-os-x-lldb-process-to-read-the-stdin

Comment: What if I need to run a command as an input? Like `cat file.bz2 | bunzip2 | myProgramThatNeedsDebugging` ?

Comment: @iAdjunct, in that case do "bunzip2 < file.bz2 > filename_with_input" before running gdb.

Comment: @j13r Ha, sorry, I'm good at finding ridiculous cases. My bzip'd file is ~500MB and, unzipped, it's roughly 80GB (file paths, lots and lots of file paths). I can't store them unzipped.

Comment: @iAdjunct I saw in another question that you can use the bash syntax, i.e., "run < <(bunzip file.bz2)"

Comment: is there any way to pipe without writing to file?

Comment: @Shinlos I'm still trying to figure out how this syntax works, but I believe, `run < <(python3 ~/exploit.py)` will work if you're trying to pipe in the output of exploit.py into the program you're currently stepping in gdb.

Comment: @JoshDesmond it does indeed work this way, I just had to change it to `run < <("\`python -c '(script)'\`")`