# Cannot get mac os x lldb process to read the STDIN

Tags: lldb

Is it me or lldb for mac os x (replacing gdb) does not allow you to pipe a file into the stdin, to be used by the process being debugged?

reading the [instructions](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) there is no reference to it.

I've gone through and installed gnu gdb, but would like to take advantage of what I suppose is improved lldb capability?

Comment: I had the same issue and figured out a solution, as can be seen here:
[Stackoverflow: cannot get lldb to read file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582881/cannot-get-lldb-to-read-file-input)

Answer (score 48):

```
(lldb) process launch -i <file>
```

Should do the trick.  Note you can't say:

```
(lldb) run -i <file>
```

since `run` is an alias for `process launch --` so all its arguments are passed to the process being launched.

There's a general "help" facility that can show you more about all the lldb commands.

```
(lldb) help process launch
```

would have shown you this option.

Comment: @Ben, can you mark this as the correct answer? It worked for me, I'm assuming it worked for you as well.

Comment: did NOT work for me on MacOS, however the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861242/cannot-get-mac-os-x-lldb-process-to-read-the-stdin did work.