# Cannot get lldb to read file input through redirect

Tags: c, macos, stdin, lldb

I'm using `lldb` as a standalone debugger in OSX. I'm trying to debug a C executable, using a text file as input, by way of a redirect. The `lldb` documentation specifies the following command for changing stdin to a given file:

```
process launch -i <file>
```

Using this command, `lldb` seems to ignore the specified file, instead waiting for keyboard input.

Is this intended behavior? If so; what do I need to do to actually get the process to operate on my wanted input file?

tl;dr: How do I get `lldb` to imitate a standard terminal execution with a redirect like:

```
./executable < <file>
```

Comment: To clarify, your application is written to always read from stdin?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I assume so, but I'm not entirely sure. My program's IO is defined in source generated by flex and bison. I call yyparse() which in turn calls yylex(), which should do the IO. The executable have, however, been run outside debugger with the textfile as stdin, and behaved as intended. It was done as follows: ./executable <inputfile.txt> outputfile.txt

Comment: `./executable infile.txt outfile.txt` does **not** mean the program is reading from stdin. In fact, it implies the opposite - that the program is expecting a filename on the command-line.  You need to look at the `int main` for your program and understand it first.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Sorry for the confusion.  `./executable <infile.txt> outfile.txt`, is from a secondary makefile (for producing output files). In terminal, I can run `./executable < infile.txt` for desired result, or just `./executable` for it to read keyboard input. As I understand it, this **is** stdin. Am I wrong?

Comment: @HaraldHusum I think he misunderstood `<inputfile.txt>` as a placeholder rather than literal shell syntax.  Your program is indeed reading from stdin.

Comment: @zwol It is easy to see why. Hence sorry for the confusion. :P

Comment: @zwol Ha, yes, you are indeed correct.  Yes, your program is reading from stdin. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I got it to work as follows:

```
lldb <executable>
(lldb) settings set target.input-path <file>
(lldb) process launch
```

It solves my problem, but I don't really have an explanation for why the method in my question *doesn't* work.

Comment: This also worked for me. I also was not able to get the `-i` option to work as many have put forth as the solution.

Comment: To run the <executable> with arguments, do `run -arg1 -arg2` instead of `process launch`.

Comment: @AlienKevin that is not what the question is about, though.

Comment: @HaraldHusum I think it's a relatively common case to run an executable with file input and arguments. I encountered this problem personally and just want to let others know how to pass those args after file redirect.

Comment: @AlienKevin ah, ok. Thought you were suggesting it as a solution. No worries then.